# Node.js nwjs package compilation error: Invalid file descriptor to ICU data

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, package.json, node-webkit

I'm trying to create my first package with nwjs, so I created a simple app with only nwjs module installed locally with npm. My app main file has only a `console.log("Hello World!")`. I zipped the app files - keeping them in the root - and renamed to `app.nw`. I basically followed [this doc](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/How-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps#step-1-make-a-package). The package tree is the following:

```
app.nw 
 - node_modules
   - nw (and all its files inside)
 - package.json
 - app.js
```

And my `package.json` is:

```
{
  "name": "app3",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "window": {
  // Some properties here
  }
}
```

Then I created an empty folder and copied `app.nw` to it. From the module folder `/nw/nwjs` I copied the files: `nw.exe`, `nw.dll`, `nw_elf.dll` and `ffmpeg.dll` to it, and dragged `app.nw` over `nw.exe`. The debug.log file shows me the following error:

> [0524/110408:ERROR:icu_util.cc(157)] Invalid file descriptor to ICU data received.
>   [0524/110408:FATAL:icu_util.cc(260)] Check failed: result.

I can't find anything related to this error and this tool over the web. I'm running it in a Win7 x64. I also tryied downloading nwjs manually from github and tryied with x64 and x86 binaries, but they all give me the same error.

Below, the backtrace if needed:

```
v8::OutputStream::WriteHeapStatsChunk [0x000007FEDA1B7AB1+225089]
std::vector<v8::CpuProfileDeoptFrame,std::allocator<v8::CpuProfileDeoptFrame> >::operator= [0x000007FEDA1640BC+259612]
v8::OutputStream::WriteHeapStatsChunk [0x000007FEDA1F2E58+467688]
v8::Extension::auto_enable [0x000007FEDA1203D1+368897]
v8::Extension::auto_enable [0x000007FEDA11ED19+363081]
ChromeMain [0x000007FED9CE0EB5+133]
GetUploadedReportsImpl [0x000000013F201251+3297]
GetUploadedReportsImpl [0x000000013F20097F+1039]
IsSandboxedProcess [0x000000013F264628+231640]
BaseThreadInitThunk [0x0000000076C359BD+13]
RtlUserThreadStart [0x0000000076E6A2E1+33]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Doesn't your main file need to be an html file in nwjs?

Comment: @GrandmasterB in fact its a html file in their examples. It is a requirement? I will try it.

Comment: @GrandmasterB I tried it, the error remains, but now its shown twice. Two `Invalid file descriptor to ICU data received` errors. It seems to be the same number of the app files, maybe.

Comment: Do have a file named icudtl.dat in the binary directory (the one with nw.exe)?

Comment: @GrandmasterB no, but I added and it required other files, which I added as well. After that, when trying to run, a message box with the error: `Failed to load extension from: path/to/app.nw. Manifest file is missing or unreadable.` although my file seems to be fine. Note that the app has no modules at all.

Comment: That sounds better - just that it can't find the source files.  Make a simple hello world html file (no javascript), put it into the same dir that the exe is in, and make that the "main" item in your json file.  If you can get that working, then its just a matter of putting your app files in the place its looking for them.

Comment: @GrandmasterB I did, and I got this error `FATAL:chrome_main_delegate.cc(525)] Failed to load node library`. [this is my structure right now](http://imgur.com/eNJIjfN). I drag and drop `app2.nw` over `nw.exe`..

Comment: I would recommend trying it without zipping up the app.  Just put the index.html & json file uncompressed in the same dir as the exe, and then run nw.exe. Or, rename the .nw file to 'package.nw'. Otherwise I'm not entirely sure whats going on there.  I've never had any problem building the exes.  You also might try nwbuild, which is a tool used for building them.

Comment: @GrandmasterB I tryied both ways but none worked. It gives me a pt error which is my os language `ERROR:file_io.cc(41)] write: O pipe está sendo fechado.`. I will try nwbuild for sure.

Comment: @GrandmasterB check my answer. Thanks for the help, man!!

Comment: Excellent!  Glad to hear you got it going!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work with the following `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "app4",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "single-instance": true,
  "package": ".json",
  "window": {
    "title": "app4",
    "toolbar": false
  }
}
```

I'm actually not sure what specific property which I removed/added to made it to work. Then I zipped it to `package.nw` and put in the same folder as `nw.exe` to run it.